# Swap Images from Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am coding a page with multiple image swaps. I want to swap two different images, however only one of them is currently working as the image iD is the same for all of the images.

I am not skilled in javascript and cannot seem to find a workaround. Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
var imgArray = new Array(
  '/en_us/local/page_specific/furniture/dining-rustique-main.jpg',
  '/en_us/local/page_specific/furniture/dining-rustique-main2.jpg',
  '/en_us/local/page_specific/furniture/dining-bonnie-main.jpg',
  '/en_us/local/page_specific/furniture/dining-bonnie-main2.jpg'

);

var imgPath = "";

function swapImage(imgID, obj) {
  var theImage = document.getElementById('theImage');
  var newImg;
  newImg = imgArray[imgID];
  theImage.src = imgPath + newImg;
  obj.src = imgPath + imgArray;
}

function preloadImages() {
  for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
    var tmpImg = new Image;
    tmpImg.src = imgPath + imgArray[i];
  }
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <div id="image"><img id="theImage" src="http://www.urbanbarn.com/images/urbanbarn/en_us/local/page_specific/furniture/dining-bonnie-main.jpg"></td>
    <td valign="top"><img src="http://www.urbanbarn.com/images/urbanbarn/en_us/local/page_specific/furniture/dining-bonnie-gif.gif"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><img src="http://www.urbanbarn.com/images/urbanbarn/en_us/local/page_specific/furniture/trail-brown.jpg" onmouseover="swapImage(3)"><img src="http://www.urbanbarn.com/images/urbanbarn/en_us/local/page_specific/furniture/trail-grey.jpg" onmouseover="swapImage(2)"></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <div id="image"><img id="theImage" src="http://www.urbanbarn.com/images/urbanbarn/en_us/local/page_specific/furniture/dining-rustique-main.jpg"></td>
    <td valign="top"><img src="http://www.urbanbarn.com/images/urbanbarn/en_us/local/page_specific/furniture/dining-rustique-gif.gif"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><img src="http://www.urbanbarn.com/images/urbanbarn/en_us/local/page_specific/furniture/rustique-sample-dark.jpg" onmouseover="swapImage(1)"><img src="http://www.urbanbarn.com/images/urbanbarn/en_us/local/page_specific/furniture/rustique-sample-pine.jpg"
        onmouseover="swapImage(0)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ids should be unique, but you can use classes multiple times. use different ids

Comment: you can still use getElementById but use the image id that's PASSED IN  as an argument to isolate the image

Comment: Hello Rachel,Thank you for your response. How do I create different IDs?

Comment: in your html, just use different ids. name them differently. do they all have the same attributes(width/height etc)? if so use a class for this and then just use an id to name them

Comment: Sorry, do you mean something like this: <img class="theImage2">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also pass the id as an argument like Rachel had suggested. Just make sure you have different IDs.

```
  <img id="theImage">
  <img id="theImage2">
```

Just make sure you pass it as an argument

```
onmouseover="swapImage(3, 'theImage')"
onmouseover="swapImage(2, 'theImage')"
onmouseover="swapImage(1, 'theImage2')"
onmouseover="swapImage(0, 'theImage2')"
```

Here's the updated function

```
function swapImage(imgID, id) {
   var theImage = document.getElementById(id);
   var newImg = imgArray[imgID];
   theImage.src = imgPath + newImg;
   id.src = imgPath + imgArray[imgID];
}
```

[Here's a codepen with it implemented.](https://codepen.io/jbanegas/full/ZyPRqd/)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @user3227561 instead of posting a "thank you", accept the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer (just hover beside the answer and click)

Comment: @JoeB. snap! (i upvoted your answer - like the codepen btw)

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of reworking the function, but when your comment suggested passing the ID as an argument I figured the majority of the code could stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript is a bit messy.

You can do this more effectively using a tidy 'swap image' function that sets the src attribute like so:

```js
var i =0;
function swapImage() {
  if (i == 0) {
    document.getElementById("myImage1").setAttribute('src', 'http://www.urbanbarn.com/images/urbanbarn/en_us/local/page_specific/furniture/rustique-sample-dark.jpg');
    i++;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myImage1").setAttribute('src', 'http://www.urbanbarn.com/images/urbanbarn/en_us/local/page_specific/furniture/rustique-sample-pine.jpg');
    i--;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="myImage1" src="http://www.urbanbarn.com/images/urbanbarn/en_us/local/page_specific/furniture/rustique-sample-pine.jpg" onclick="swapImage();" border="0" />
<!--or on mouseout, whatever-->
```

You can adapt this function to create a second mouseover

Answer (score 0):

An ID should not be used more than once in an HTML file, and as such, getElementById only gets one element. Use a class and the getQuerySelectorAll method instead.

Comment: If you can provide documentation to support this, it would be a much better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Id attributes should be unique. If 2 elements have the same id, `document.getElementById` will only return the first 1. You should use the class attribute and `document.getElementsByClassName`.

If you are really unable to change this, you could use `document.querySelectorAll('[id=theImage]')`.

Also here you are adding an array to a string:

```
obj.src = imgPath + imgArray;
```

So your `.src`s aren't getting swapped properly.

Comment: var imgPath = "";
  
   function swapImage(imgID) {
    var theImage = document.querySelectorAll('[id=theImage]').
    var newImg;
    newImg = imgArray[imgID];
    theImage.src = imgPath + newImg;
   
   }
   
   function swapImage(imgID) {
    var theImage = document.querySelectorAll('[id=theImage2]').
    var newImg;
    newImg = imgArray[imgID];
    theImage.src = imgPath + newImg;
    
   }